# Prevent default event - jquery

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I know it's a question that comes back often in many posts but even after reading dozens of answers, I still can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

The point is to prevent default submit and retrieve the response data in the answer div. What the code actually does is sending me directly to the geocoder.php page.

Thanks a lot,

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("geostring").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      term = $form.find( 'input[name="geo"]' ).val(),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
    $( "#answer" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>



<form action="http://winefy.alwaysdata.net/geocoder.php" method="POST" id="geostring">
<input type=text name="geo" placeholder="Address..." />
<input type="submit" value="Geocode" />
<div id="answer"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. As [DCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233508/dcoder) points out in the comments below, your selector is missing the `#`. It should be `$("#geostring")`, not `$("geostring")`.
2. You're trying to attach the handler before the `form` element exists. So `$("#geostring")` returns an empty jQuery set and no handler is hooked up.

   Just put the `script` tag **after** the `form`.

   ```
   <form action="http://winefy.alwaysdata.net/geocoder.php" method="POST" id="geostring">
   <input type=text name="geo" placeholder="Address..." />
   <input type="submit" value="Geocode" />
   <div id="answer"></div>
   </form>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

   <script>
   /* attach a submit handler to the form */
   $("#geostring").submit(function(event) {

     /* stop form from submitting normally */
     event.preventDefault();

     /* get some values from elements on the page: */
     var $form = $( this ),
         term = $form.find( 'input[name="geo"]' ).val(),
         url = $form.attr( 'action' );

     /* Send the data using post */
     var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

     /* Put the results in a div */
     posting.done(function( data ) {
       var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
       $( "#answer" ).empty().append( content );
     });
   });
   </script>
   ```

   More:

   - [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)
   - [Google Closure engineers on when DOM elements are ready to script](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E/RjllWWJTXAcJ)

   Alternately, if you aren't in control of where the `script` tags go for some reason, you can use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) event to delay your code until the DOM loads.

   ```
   $(function() {
       // ...your code here...
   });
   ```

   or more verbosely:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // ...your code here...
   });
   ```

Comment: @Crowder Isin't the script executed only after loading all HTML elements by the browser ?

Comment: @Vivek: No, the script is executed as soon as the `script` tag is encountered.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I just made the change but it doesn't work...

I use this code in a Joomla View of a custom component, does it change anything ?

Comment: @user1007015: The selector does not actually match the form (the leading # is missing).

Comment: @DCoder: **OMG** How did I miss that?

Comment: @user1007015: See DCoder's comment above (and the new item #1 in the answer above).

Comment: THANKS A LOT !
I think it's working. (at least the php page doesn't load :)

Thanks a lot Crowder,Vivek and DCoder.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the common approach:

```
<form onsubmit="return myFunc();"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc(){
    // Your jQuery Code
    return false;
}
</script>
```